# Combine deploy key with GitLab API to push commits directly protected branch

Tags: gitlab, cicd, gitlab-api

I have a protected master branch on GitLab where no one can push except a deployed key I have created under settings->repository->Deploy keys.
My ssh keys is stored in `~/.ssh/id_deploy` and the corresponding (.pub) file.

Following this, I try the following:

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/repository/submodules/sub" 
--data "branch=master&commit_sha=3ddec28ea23acc5caa5d8331a6ecb2a65fc03e88&commit_message=Update submodule reference"
```

Note that the above command (with the correct token and gitlab url/project id) has also been tried against another branch not being protected and that worked.

However, when I try it against master I get a message saying I `cannot push to that branch`.

I wonder if what I attempting to do is possible, and how else I could achieve this without unprotecting my branch

Comment: you are not using ssh but http - does that private token have access?

Comment: the private token seems to work fine as long as I dont push to the protected branch. The token is created by enabled the api scope which grants both read and write access, and it created for the project in question

Comment: does it have permission to push to that branch - i.e. bypass the restriction?

Comment: the scope is set to api which seems to be the most relaxed restriction, and its role is a maintainer. Is there another way to grant even more access?

Comment: The access token is created under the project,i.e. project->settings->access tokens

Comment: I dont see any other way how to allow the tokens to bypass restrictions?

Comment: I think this is what you want: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#allow-deploy-keys-to-push-to-a-protected-branch